# List index out of range web crawler Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-crawler

I am making a web crawler that exhausts every webpage. I am given the first link of `http://www.someURL.com/42342`. On this page is `X` number of lines of expressions. The `parse` and `evaluate` functions I have evaluate these expressions to numbers. With these numbers, I concatenate them to a default link (`http://www.someURL.com/`) to go to another link. I am trying to keep count how many webpages there are but I am currently running into this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 72, in <module>
    print url_queue(convert_to_link(URL)) 
  File "test2.py", line 23, in url_queue
    new_urls = convert_to_link(url)
  File "test2.py", line 13, in convert_to_link
    num_list.append(evaluate(parse(expressions)))
  File "test2.py", line 62, in evaluate
    return stack[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm not quite sure why. Each function seems to give the correct output. Could someone help point out where my logic is wrong in my code?

My code:

```
import urllib2

URL = 'http://www.someURL.com/42342'

def convert_to_link(url):      
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    output_expressions = response.read().splitlines()   #return each expression in a list
    num_list = []
    url_list = []
    for expressions in output_expressions:
        num_list.append(evaluate(parse(expressions)))
    for number in num_list:
        url_list.append(newpage_gen(number))
    return url_list

def url_queue(url_list):
    count = 0
    for url in url_list:
        new_urls = convert_to_link(url)
        url_list.extend(new_urls)
        count += 1
    return count

def parse (s):          # parse expression
    s = s.replace('(', ' ').replace(')', ' ').replace(',', ' ')
    return s.split()[::-1]

def evaluate (ops):     # evaluate expression
    stack = []
    while ops:
        op = ops[0]
        ops = ops[1:]
        try:
            stack.append(int(op))
            continue
        except: pass
        if op == 'add':
            arg1, arg2 = stack.pop(), stack.pop()
            stack.append(arg1 + arg2)
            continue
        if op == 'multiply':
            arg1, arg2 = stack.pop(), stack.pop()
            stack.append(arg1 * arg2)
            continue
        if op == 'abs':
            arg1 = stack.pop()
            stack.append(abs(arg1))
            continue
        if op == 'subtract':
            arg1, arg2 = stack.pop(), stack.pop()
            stack.append(arg1 - arg2)
            continue
    return stack[0]

def newpage_gen(page_num):      # create new link
    url_template = 'http://www.someURL.com/'
    new_url = url_template + str(page_num)
    return new_url

print "TESTING"
print url_queue(convert_to_link(URL))
```

Comment: Can you post the expression that causes the problem? For example, the output of `print ops` when you enter the evaluate function?

Comment: @Liondancer Are you expecting those if statements to trigger every time? Is there ever a scenario where none of them should evaluate to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If stack is empty, stack[0] will give that error.

Stack will be empty if there are no ops, is a blank line.

I would wonder if your input file has a blank line or two at the end of it.

Comment: hmm okay I will look into that

Comment: Well there are two other outputs that a link can display which are difference from the expressions. This is probably why the stack is empty. I forgot to take account of this thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Like @Hugh Bothwell said, stack is probably empty. Try replacing your code with this to determine the error:

```
if op == 'add':
        arg1, arg2 = stack.pop(), stack.pop()
        stack.append(arg1 + arg2)
        continue
else if op == 'multiply':
        arg1, arg2 = stack.pop(), stack.pop()
        stack.append(arg1 * arg2)
        continue
else if op == 'abs':
        arg1 = stack.pop()
        stack.append(abs(arg1))
        continue
else if op == 'subtract':
        arg1, arg2 = stack.pop(), stack.pop()
        stack.append(arg1 - arg2)
        continue
else: 
        print "UNEXPECTED INPUT!!"+op
```